# Openshift installation error for etcd?

Tags: openshift, redhat-containers

Trying to install Openshift-Enterprise getting the following error during the pre-requisites check phase.

```
    TASK [Evaluate groups - Fail if no etcd hosts group is defined] *************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Running etcd as an embedded service is no longer supported. If this is a new install please define an 'etcd' group with either one, three or five hosts. These hosts may be the same hosts as your masters. If this is an upgrade please see https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/install_config/upgrading/migrating_embedded_etcd.html for documentation on how to migrate from embedded to external etcd.\n"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/usr/share/ansible/openshift-ansible/playbooks/prerequisites.retry

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I have defined an etcd host group with same host as master. Following is the ansible hosts file for insight to my cluster config:

```
    # Create an OSEv3 group that contains the masters, nodes, and etcd groups
[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd

# Set variables common for all OSEv3 hosts
[OSEv3:vars]
# SSH user, this user should allow ssh based auth without requiring a password
ansible_ssh_user=root
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth',
'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true',
'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider',
'filename': '/etc/origin/master/htpasswd'}]
openshift_use_etcd_system_container=True
# If ansible_ssh_user is not root, ansible_become must be set to true
openshift_deployment_type=openshift-enterprise
#ansible_become=true

openshift_deployment_type=openshift-enterprise
# uncomment the following to enable htpasswd authentication; defaults to DenyAllPasswordIdentityProvider
#openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider', 'filename': '/etc/origin/master/htpasswd'}]
openshift_logging_install_logging=true
openshift_logging_es_pvc_dynamic=true
openshift_metrics_install_metrics=true
openshift_metrics_cassandra_storage_type=dynamic
# host group for masters
[masters]
ip-172-31-7-82.us-west-2.compute.internal

# host group for etcd
[etcd]
ip-172-31-7-82.us-west-2.compute.internal
# host group for nodes, includes region info
[nodes]
ip-172-31-8-41.us-west-2.compute.internal openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was solved by Openshift in a later release